# Force lattice to use a label for all axis ticks

Tags: r, lattice, axis-labels

I am generating a plot with xyplot from the lattice package. I use the following command:

```
xyplot(Y ~ X | Bench, dt, type = 'o')
```

And this is the result:

[image: sample image]

On the Y axis there is a tick without label (0.85). Is there  any way to force lattice to print a label next to the tick (as it does for all the others: 1.00, 0.95 and 0.90)?

**EDIT:** I'm aware of some "manual" ways to tweak a plot in such a way that all the ticks have a corresponding label. But the methods I know of depend on the actual data being plotted, and they may require adjustments if the data changes. I'm looking for an *automatic* solution to this. Like some sort of flag that instructs `xyplot` not to leave a tick without its associated label. Of course, it might just happen such a flag does not exist... Knowing that would be helpful too.

Comment: Use the `ylim` argument.

Comment: namely `ylim = range(Y)`

Comment: @RScriv I know that I can tweak a plot with `ylim` until all the ticks have a label. I was looking for a more general solution. Something to force lattice to use a label if there is a tick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify axis tick locations explicitly using the `scales=` argument, which skips the automatic axis label clipping:

```
xyplot(..., scales=list(y=list(at=seq(.85, 1, .05)), x=list(at=...)))
```

**EDIT:** Here you go, more automated:

```
axis.overlap <- function(..., components) {
  components$bottom$labels$check.overlap <- FALSE
  axis.default(..., components=components)
}
```

Then anytime you want to include axis-overlapping labels, you can specify:

```
xyplot(Y ~ X | Bench, dt, axis=axis.overlap)
```

or wrap it as you please:

```
xyplot2 <- function(..., axis=axis.overlap) xyplot(..., axis=axis)

xyplot2(Y ~ X | Bench, dt)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I have updated my question to make it clear that I'm looking for an automated solution, rather than an ad hoc one.

Comment: How does the axis.overlap function work? How do I actually use it to add custom labels?

Answer (score 2):

`scales=list(alternating=3)` should do the trick.

See https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lattice/versions/0.20-41/topics/B_00_xyplot for other possible values of alternating